# Can't select an entry point with MageUI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

I'm publishing my wpf application using ClickOnce, however i also want to obfuscate it.
I am publishing my application to a local folder, obfuscating it, then resigning it using mageui and then uploading it to my web server.
The problem is, I can't seem to define my executable as an entry point, every time i select it, it will default back to an empty file type.
The weird thing is, this happens even if i don't obfuscate my assembly and try to resign it as is. I can define other dlls I've referenced as entry points (which isn't their use of course), but not the executable that starts my application.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using the wrong version of mageui.exe for your project.

If you invoke mageui.exe from, for example, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin you may not be able to set the entry point on your main executable, as you have found out.

Instead, go one folder deeper to NETFX 4.0 Tools (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools) and try use mageui.exe from there. It should work...

Answer (score 0):

To set an entry point, on the files tab in the file list -- when you populate the files in the application manifest, there's a file type column -- one of the dropdown items is an entry point. Nice little hidden feature, eh?

Comment: That wasn't the problem. The problem was my dlls weren't recognized as valid entry points, every time i tried to set them as such they simply reset.